# Adjust Position of Text with CSS

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, css

I need to move the text shown in the slide component in order to center it.

Here is the site: http://cmarosac-cp52.webjoomla.es/fav/

The class is: flex-caption

```
.flex-caption {
width: 25%;
height: 96%;
padding: 2%; 
margin: 0; 
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
color: #fff; 
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
font-size: 14px; 
line-height: 20px;
}
```

I would like to locate what is the path for the file where I use the class flex-caption.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following CSS:

```
.flex-caption {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

This will extend the caption box to the full width and position it at the bottom of the slider.

You need to go to line **252** of:

> modules/mod_simple_responsive_slideshow/theme/flexslider.css

I assume you used your browser console to get the CSS for this element, so I hope you realise the browser console also tells you where the code is located ;)

Hope this helps

Comment: In addition, you should add `text-align:center` in order to center the text. But I recommend using a css override, see *General Usage* in [this post](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template), or your changes might be lost if you upgrade the module later.

Comment: My objective is <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/up8xhpgp1/slide.jpg"> I can locate flexslider.css, my problem is locating the file that is using the class flex-caption. I suposse that this file must be index.php.... but I´m not sure.

Comment: I could simply say reduce the height and add a top padding but that's not a very good approach. The best method would be to create a template override and wrap the caption text `p` element within a relatively positioned div, then start messing around with the CSS

Comment: Lodder, could you say me where I could find the file where I have to modify the classes for P element? I´ve  been searched but I can't find it... I'm new with templates desing

Comment: Probably something like `modules/mod_simple_responsive_slideshow/tmpl/default.php` but not entirely sure as I don't know this module

Comment: There is not a default.php file under slide module...

Comment: In which case I don't know. You will have to find the view file yourself

Comment: Move what? You need to find the view file for the slideshow module, not move anything

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to achieve what you ask for in your image, due to the (poor) way the slider renders it's code.

[image]

But here's a suggestions on how you can center the text vertically:

```
 /* Add left padding to go clear of arrow */
 p.flex-caption {padding-left: 50px;}

 /* Add empty box above */
 p.flex-caption:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 35%;
}
```

This will not center the text exactly, but close.