# Hide languages from the Language Switcher

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, overrides, language, mod-languages

I have a question about the Joomla language switcher module. I would like to hide the option to switch to English language on the website. I can't unpublish the English language because then it says the English site doesn't exist anymore. But I need it to exist because its accessed from different link.

[image]

Comment: thinking ... hmmm, then what is the point to have a link for the current language on the website... I mean that from your description people will already seeing the Hrvatski version of the website, why to have a language selection for the same language?

Comment: Default language is Slovenian-SI, but i also need option for Hrvatski-HR. I cant unpublish English-UK because the entire English site stops working. So basicly SI/HR are accessed from same link, EN version is accessed from entierly diffrent link. www.aeq.si  <- SI/HR    http://www.somatics.si/ <- EN only

Comment: i know this thread is very old but... i can't find that line on the default.php file.
Any idea?

Comment: @94a94 - If you have the same or similar problem and none of the answers here is able to solve it, then I would suggest you to create a new question add all relevant information and references to this question in order to get an answer. Also - and this is very important - before you do anything familiarise with how JSE works, how to ask questions, post answers, etc following: [help] and [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the file `modules\mod_languages\tmpl\default.php` to `templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\mod_languages\default.php` to create a template override for the language module.
2. Locate the following line in your template override (aprox. line 32 in Joomla 3.3):

   ```
   <li class="<?php echo $language->active ? 'lang-active' : '';?>" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
   ```

   Replace with this (adding `echo $language->title_native;`):

   ```
   <li class="<?php echo $language->active ? 'lang-active' : ''; echo ' ' . $language->lang_code; ?>" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
   ```

   This will add the language code to the `<li>` tags, giving you `<li class="active en-GB"...` and allow you to target any language using CSS.
3. Finally, add this code to your template's CSS stylesheet (replace `en-GB` with the language you want to hide):

   ```
   .en-GB {
       display: none!important;
   }
   ```

Comment: the quick way of hiding things on the browser

Comment: Yes @FFrewin, using CSS in this case is a "quick-and-dirty" solution, yours is a bit more advanced.

Comment: in what folder do i create css file and what filename do i give it ? Im am new to joomla

Comment: That depends on your template. I recommend you take a look at [this post](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template) for more details on how to add custom CSS code to your template.

Comment: Ok i did all those things, now how do i override the template, do i have to check something in CMS ?

Comment: @Matthew - Johan has already showed you how to override the view for the module at the beginning of the question. You simply copy to *default.php* file to the directory he showed you. See [here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for more info

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work www.aeq.si

Comment: It doesn't look like you did the override correctly, because your source code looks like this now: `<li class dir="ltr">`. It should read `<li class="en-GB" dir="ltr">`. Make sure you copied the code above exactly (looks like you missed something).
Another solution is to add this CSS code to your template: `ul.lang-inline li:last-child {display: none;}`. That will hide the last language link.

Comment: http://puu.sh/d8KhQ/7c67ce2d50.png , the only thing i can think of being wrong is maybe i put a wrong folder name ? This is the original file path : http://puu.sh/d8Km7/71b2f088c6.png

Comment: According to your images, your override is in the `mattsLang` template folder, but your website is using the `rt_hadron` template. You have to place the override in `templates\rt_hadron\html\mod_languages` folder, as this is your active template.

Comment: i put that mod_languages in 4 folders, http://puu.sh/d8RGQ/ee7a34d5ec.png ,http://puu.sh/d8RLH/585a1cff28.png , http://puu.sh/d8RS1/b8a2b09fca.png <- and first two on this picutre. And it still doesn't append classes.

Comment: Then I have no idea what's wrong. Can you please paste the entire contents of your override (`mod_languages/default.php`) in your original question?

Answer (score 2):

Following Anibal's answer and the link on how to create a module template override or alternative layout... here is a piece of code you could use inside the template file of the languages module.

The template of the module is checking for the settings you have defined in the module manager, about how to display the languages.

Part of code is like this:

```
    <?php if ($params->get('show_active', 0) || !$language->active):?>

        <li class="<?php echo $language->active ? 'lang-active' : '';?>" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>">
        <?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/' . $language->image . '.gif', $language->title_native, array('title' => $language->title_native), true);?>
        <?php else : ?>

                <?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef);?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

It uses foreach loop, to loop through the available content languages and will display them.
Inside the foreach loop and right after its beginning and before its end, you can wrap the executed code with a conditional check like below:

This goes after the beginning of the foreach loop:

```
<?php if ($language->lang_code != 'en-GB') {?>
```

This will make the code that renders the language menus, only if the language of the menu is not english.

This closes and wrap your if statement, just before the closing of the foreach loop.

```
<?php } ?>
```

**So you should end up with something like this:**

```
<?php foreach ($list as $language) : ?>
    <?php if ($language->lang_code != 'en-GB') {?> // Don't run if it's english.
    <?php if ($params->get('show_active', 0) || !$language->active):?>

        <li class="<?php echo $language->active ? 'lang-active' : '';?>" dir="<?php echo JLanguage::getInstance($language->lang_code)->isRTL() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>">
        <?php if ($params->get('image', 1)):?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('image', 'mod_languages/' . $language->image . '.gif', $language->title_native, array('title' => $language->title_native), true);?>
        <?php else : ?>

                <?php echo $params->get('full_name', 1) ? $language->title_native : strtoupper($language->sef);?>

        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif;?> 
            <?php } ?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new module layout, showing only the languages you need.

**Module Alternative Layouts**
http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla#Module_Alternative_Layouts