# Joomla not always displaying webpage correctly

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

so my problem with my webpage [NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com/) is that it does not display it correctly on the web. On my localhost the page looks fine. Strangly when i put it on the web it looks fine first but after a while the position changes. Does anyone know how to fix this?

How the page should look like (localhost):
[image]

Comment: Some free web hosting providers add some html/JavaScript/CSS codes to the rendered pages. This would make elements untidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I use Google Chrome development tools a lot so I can easily assign values to properties. what I did is just copy/paste the CSS code from Chrome to the appropriate CSS file. Turns out to be that The development tools assign a wrong class or/and id. Changed some classes and everything works fine now

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving enough information, `after a while the position changes` is not very helpful.

Here's a couple of common reasons for layout errors:

1. Make sure you've transferred all your files to the server. If possible, use [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup.html) and [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html).
2. Make sure you've included your custom CSS files properly. Take a look at [this post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/3878#3878) for a couple of alternatives. I don't know if you have a `custom.css` file, but if you do, it's not loaded in your source code. These are the CSS files I could see in your source code:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/Header.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/Bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/Latest-Articles.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/Top-Articles.css" type="text/css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/protostar/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
   ```

   (the rest are extension specific)
3. Make sure your code contains no absolute paths to `http://localhost` or relative paths that aren't valid on your live server.
4. Clear both your browsers cache and Joomla cache.