# Edit template from source code

Tags: templates, css

I've been asked to maintain a website that is built in Joomla, using a template from YOOTheme.

I'm not used to it since I've never used Joomla. I usually do my stuff from scratch.

So my question is, can I simply access this website via FTP and edit all my styling and stuff from Source Code?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing a little research on how Joomla works. [This](https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Beginners) might be a place to begin, and other resources can be found [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Tutorials:Beginners). A Google search might also give you some answers.

Basically, you manage a Joomla site through the admin area (http://example.com/administrator), and if you have Joomla 3.x or above you can also edit the template from the admin area.

In addition, you can usually make adjustments to the template from the Joomla template manager (**Extensions** -> **Template Manager** -> select the name of your active template). Depending on your template, you should be able to change colors, logo, and other parameters there.

You can absolutely edit files through FTP, but it's highly recommended to avoid editing core files (both Joomla and extensions), as these might be overridden if you update Joomla (and you should ALWAYS keep Joomla up to date). You can edit your template files, and if you need other modifications to Joomla or some of your extensions you can use a [template overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core). This is basically a way of adding `.php` files to your template folder that will be used by Joomla instead of the core files.

If you're stuck with anything, or have a questions, you're more than welcome to ask your questions here, and you'll almost certainly get answers.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time.

This website is already running. I've been messing around in Administrator Panel but It doesn't really give me control of what I want. Somethink like hover transitions and stuff. That's why I'm looking to edit css files like I'm used to

Comment: I have some pending updates. Is it always safe to update?

Comment: It's always safe to update within the same version (2.5.x or 3.x), but it's always a good idea to make a backup first. I recommend [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/akeeba-backup.html), an easy way to backup both Joomla and your database. You can edit the CSS files from your template, or use CSS overrides ([this post](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/3878#3878) talks about how to do CSS overrides).

Answer (score 0):

Yea of course. I tend to use Filezilla for ftp and NetBeans as an IDE. YooTheme will have loads of tutorials online also.