# Joomla 3 - Tooltips

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I'm using a template of Shape 5, called GCK Store.

I would like to remove the TOOLTIPS from the inputs fields, or at least, improve them with CSS, but I don't find any solution... do you have any idea about how to disable them?

[image]

**LINK OF THE WEBSITE: http://tienda.ganeshgrow.es/**

Comment: Have a look at your css using firebug (or give us the link to your website), then create a css override to disable them - explained well here http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template

Answer (score 2):

inside the configuration area of the template there is an option to disable them, they are also disabled by default, so someone turned it on.

Comment: I will see. Tell you on Monday

Comment: I did it, but it didn't work... any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in your template index.php to try and remove the script - near the top of the page:

```
if (isset($this->_script['text/javascript']))
{
    $this->_script['text/javascript'] = preg_replace('/put the regex for your script here /', '', $this->_script['text/javascript']);


if (empty($this->_script['text/javascript']))
 unset($this->_script['text/javascript']);  
    }
```

A good way to generate your regex is here:
http://regexr.com/

You need to enter it at the top of the page after:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
```

Comment: You mean, before Doctype?

Comment: after <? defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); - see answer above

Comment: I dont really understand how to use REGEX plugin

Comment: 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php - 2. put the javascript that you want removed here "http://regexr.com/" and use the regex codes to remove it 3. the URL  http://tienda.ganeshgrow.es/ - doesn't show the contact box