# How to override a module js file

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, overrides

Is possible override a js file of a module in template?
The path of js file is modules/my_module/js/file.js

Thank so much!

Comment: This is for CSS, but the same applies for JS: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/13940/168

Answer (score 2):

Both the following options should be reasonably future proof so the changes survive extension and Joomla updates.

**Option 1: Module Override**

I don't think you can override a JavaScript file but you could create a module override as per https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides and replace the code where the JavaScript file is called with a call to an alternative JavaScript file.

**Option 2: jQuery Easy**

The free version of [jQuery Easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) can help with removing and adding scripts although it may depend on how the script is being loaded if jQuery Easy can help in this case or not.