# Parent menu item not marked if sub menu item is active

Tags: module, joomla-3.4, menu-item, menu

As the title says, when one of sub menu items is active, parents of that item are not marked in any way.

I'm using latest default Joomla and stock menu module without any overrides and mods.

I remember this was a feature in previous releases of Joomla but now it's gone.

Does anyone have a simple solution / override for this?

Comment: Have you tried default protostar template? I tested it with Joomla 3.4.7 and Protostar enabled and parents items are like: `<li class="item-111 active deeper parent">` (on a category/category/articles structure)

Comment: I have not, I'll check that out, but I thought maybe I'm missing some option or something, because I remember that being standard behaviour in 2.5

Answer (score 0):

This likely depends on the menu or template that is in use on your website.

As per the comments, try one or more of the default templates.

You can likely achieve the behaviour you are after by overriding the CSS of the template using a custom CSS file or similar (see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for details).