# Joomla Search - Remove "Ordering" Drop-down menu

Tags: search

How do I remove the "Ordering" drop-down menu option from Joomla Search?

I need to remove the Green highlight section not the Red section by setting 'Use Search Options' to 'No'.

Thanks!

[image: A Screenshot of the area I wish to remove]

Comment: For a Joomla template "theme1616" how would you accomplish this? In terms of getting rid of "Search For:" and "ordering".

Answer (score 1):

**Search Options**

Setting `Components -> Search -> Options ->  Use Search Options` to "No" will disable the search options.

**CSS Override**

Alternatively, you could hide the ordering option this via CSS as follows:

```
.ordering-box {
    display: none;
}
```

or possibly:

```
.ordering-box {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This may depend on the template you are using. For example, this seems to be correct for the JSN Solid Pro template if the [demo](http://demo.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn_solid/pro/index.php?option=com_search&view=search) is anything to go by:

[image: JSN Solid Template Search Option]

Taking JSN templates as an example, copy the custom CSS code into a custom file e.g. `custom.css` and copy the file to the CSS folder at `/templates/[template name]/css`. Remember to specify the name of the CSS file at `Extensions -> Templates -> [template name] -> SEO & System -> Custom CSS/JS File(s)`.

See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for instructions on adding custom CSS files to other templates.

Comment: I had already set my 'Use Search Options' to 'No', removing the section highlighted in red in the new screenshot. But I need to remove the 'Ordering' drop-down menu highlighted in green in the new screenshot. I tried placing in the suggested CSS into my custom.css but it did not remove the 'Ordering' section. Do you have any other advice? Thanks!

Comment: It might help to say what template you are using or ideally post a link to your website.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I am using JSN Solid Pro template, http://www.joomlashine.com/joomla-templates/jsn-solid-joomla-template-details.html . But unfortunately my site is a internal portal on the company network so I cannot provide access. But any suggestions you can offer would help me and my team so much. I really appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Check that your CSS override is active by browsing to your custom CSS file at `http://[your-web-site]/templates/[template-name]/css/custom.css` or similar to confirm the code is present. You may need to clear the Joomla cache etc to ensure that the latest version of the custom CSS file is loading.