# How to fix missing article separator (Joomla 3.4.8)?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, articles, layout, category-blog

I have a Joomla website that missing article separator (featured article menu,and category blog to be precise),while my other Joomla site the article separator still showing up. Both updated to Joomla 3.4.8.

So it has ugly blog layout now.

I don't know for sure since when this issue came up. I guess after updating my Joomla from 3.4.5 to 3.4.8.

What should I do?

Is there any configuration? Or any handcode? Anyone?

Ps: Have been changing up to 3 different template, and that won't fix my problem. And have been googling that there should be item-separator class in it's css, but I didn't find anything on mine.

**Edit**
The site is http://karinakas.or.id/

Comment: It might be advisable to post a link to your site, so we can check it for ourselves. This way is very hard to tell what might be the problem.

Comment: @MirkoMikan I've added the site link in my question, thank's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you provided it is obvious that in your template there IS NO article-separator HTML element. From the name of your template, 'favourite' I guess it is one of free templates from FavThemes, and it is obviously of not so great quality.

Anyway, you can quickly add following CSS rule at the end of file
`/templates/favourite/css/template.css`

> article {
>   border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
>   padding-bottom: 30px;
>   }

and adjust it or add any other CSS property to your liking.

**UPDATE:**

Modifyng `template.css` or any other template's CSS file, is generally considered bad idea, because of possibility that changes could be overwritten by future template updates.

That is why many template vendors have separate `custom.css` or `user.css` file which is always called last in the line and it does not get overwritten by template updates. Even Joomla's built-in template Protostar will have `user.css` from v3.5.0 upwards.

Comment: That is correct. The funny thing is, at first I use onecause paid template. And the article separator works fine. Then suddenly it is gone. So I try to use another 2 template, the result is the same. Wondering about that, then I check all of its css. Neither of it has article separator. Then I check my other site with working article separator (opentoko.com), it don't have either, but works. I'll report it when it is done.

Comment: It works like a charm!

Comment: @adadion - If you go with this approach, your changes are going to be overridden in the Joomla 3.5.0 update that's being released in the next few days. I'd suggest remembering this comment, then seeing my answer that applies for 3.5.0 here: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15597/168

Comment: @Lodder thank you for your remark, but the OP is not using Protostar template, but Favourite from FavThemes. I don't beleive that anything from 3rd-party template gets overwritten by Joomla update.

Comment: @Lodder thanks for the note. But I kind of agree with MirkoMikan 's comment. I think any 3rd party extension won't be overridden by Joomla's update. But that's good remark in case I use Joomla's default template.

Comment: @MirkoMikan - My bad. Didn't even see the link

Comment: @MirkoMikan as your updated answer, to be honest, I haven't use it because template update ocassionally, and some there's no update at all, but it's a good call. I already put it in custom.css. :)

Answer (score 2):

Then write the css by yourself. Normally this class should be integrated in all modern templates, maybe you do use an override for featured and category blog. More details would be needed, for e.g. a link.

To separate them with a border write in css (an example, it depends on your html structure)

```
article:after {
  border-bottom:3px solid #ccc;
}
.item-separator {
  width: inherit; 
  height: 10px; 
  border: 3px solid #ccc; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Will try later, need to other work. And I've added the site link in my question if you want to check it out, thank's. I'll report it once it done.