# Website for Famous People Profile Database

Tags: database, profile

Hellow Joomla Experts,

My client wants a website which will showcase famous and influential people profiles. Something like this => http://www.forbes.com/profile/charles-dunstone/

It should have the following functionalities:

1) Show profile of the Person (Name, Short Bio, Full Bio, DOB, Photo, Achievements, etc.)

2) Profiles categorized based on their contribution to the society (Example: Movies, Politics, Religion, Business etc)

3) Also create profiles for the famous person's family (Father, Mother, Husband/wife, son, daughter) and link them on the person's profile.

4) A search module to search famous people by their name (Will joomla's default search module work for this?)

5) Show live updates(posts/tweets) from their social media accounts (twitter, instagram) on their profile.

6) Module to show other famous people related to the person/profile displayed (just like related articles module for joomla articles)

I found this extension -> http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/extendeddb-people  Can this help?  Or this one =>  http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/profile-pro-for-community-builder

Thank you so much in advance..

Comment: Only bespoke components are going to do exactly what you need.  If you want to know if a third party extension is close enough.... erm... why not just install it / load up the demo and have a play?

Answer (score 3):

From my experiences, extending from an available component can be difficult to maintain in the long run. And extending from the component could be a hassle as the coding style are different and definitely some sort of customization would be needed to be done by your side.

What I am trying to say is, if the client is paying good why not just could a custom component yourself?

Comment: Hey Norman, thank you for the input..  I don't know to create a component. Any idea where I can find one? I will keep this as last option :)

Comment: @fmstatic59 This is the official link for Joomla! custom component tutorial. [link](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component)

Comment: @fmstatic59 Joomla! component is using MVC so you can look into that as well. MVC is basically Model, View, Controller.

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable info Norman!!  I'm not sure if I will be able to create a component. I know only basics of programming. You think its easy to do this??

Comment: @fmstatic59 If you only have basic programming skills I would recommend to make use of the available components in the extensions page of Joomla!. But if you would like to take this opportunity to learn then perhaps you can give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

**Easy Profile**

[Easy Profile](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/user-management/easy-profile) will do most of the heavy lifting for you (including search) in this scenario.

This extension is extremely versatile and fairly easy to customise to your requirements. For example, you can specify custom SQL WHERE details in "Easy Profile - User List" modules to limit your search based on the values of standard or custom fields.

You might need to override the styling via a [custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) or similar if you are fussy about how it looks but this is fairly easy to do.

Comment: Thank you Neil..  Easy Profile looks great but its more of a social networking extension. I just need to display profiles of famous people and do the above mentioned things  :)

Comment: I'm using Easy Profile as a simple directory and it will do at least 1 to 5 of your requirements and probably no. 6 too via a custom "Related People" field. Or as others have suggested, code it using a component builder, CCK, ChronoForms or similar (but this would probably require ten times the effort).

Comment: For a project this big where the entries aren't users, there's no need to use a profile extension. I'd go with Zoo or K2 or even one of the beefier (and more complex) CCKs. You have to think of this as a catalog, not a bunch of user profiles.

Comment: Hey Brian,  that was some really valuable feedback..  I totally agree with you that we cannot consider the entries as profiles but rather as a catalog.  I was thinking of using www.component-creator.com to create a simple component..  What's your opinion on this??

Comment: Thank you Neil for your advice.  I should check CCK and Chrono Forms. Thank you once again!!

Comment: Actually @Brian is right. You'd be better off with a CCK or directory extension.

Comment: If you're skilled enough, absolutely make your own because it'll do what you want. I've actually done what you're looking for (it's basically a directory) in both K2 and Zoo. Zoo actually HAS a directory with an alpha bar across the top. You can customize the layout and add extra fields.