# Where does the shadow class come from? (purity iii, pricing table1)

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, css, bootstrap, t3-framework

theres this line of code:

[image: code]

Where does the shadow att and the other css come from?
I only know the box-shadow attribute.
I know i simply can delete the att, but i am interested in where it comes from. This is for the other css too, i only see bootstrap.css files in firebug, but to search and edit them is not really best practise i think and so i am stuck because i want the the table to be a bit more compact/costumized.

The shadow:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you exactly what file this comes from, since the Purity iii demo seems to compress and combine the CSS files, but the `shadow` class has the following CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pricing-table .col.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
}
```

It's not recommended to edit the existing CSS files (Template files, Bootstrap, Joomla CSS etc.). As you might know, CSS stands for **Cascading Style Sheet**, so you can simply override the styles using your own [custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/3878#3878).

In this file you can simply place any class/ID's that you want to change in your template.

To change how the `.shadow` class looks, add something like this to your custom CSS file:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pricing-table .col.shadow {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Purity iii pricing table shadow]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you understand the difference, but the shadow you see there, is not a **css property** like `box-shadow`, `text-align` etc, but a **class name** for the **class attribute** of that **html element**.

The only connection it has with the css box-shadow property, is that it uses this name, so to create an easily identified/memorized predefined **css rule-set**, to be used to add shadow on multiple elements.

If you want to disable, you will have to create a css override, with your own rule-set, that will take precedence over the existing one.

I haven't check johanpw's answer if it works, but I trust him it will. So follow his suggestions in order to create your **custom.css**.