# Capitals Always Appearing in Heading

Tags: joomla-3.4

Can someone let me know why my heading alway appear as Capitals, even the configuration in Joomla is lowercase?

See images
[image: CAPITALS]

[image]

Comment: Most likely it's in your css. if you share a link to the page with those headings we could give the exact answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding here you go http://www.keylooplabs.com/index.php/workbooks-2/pan-edu-201/module-1-platforms-and-architecture/single-pass-architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you posted requires login to display the content, however I checked other pages and found that your h1 headings are set to be shown as uppercase in your template's css, line 63:

```
/templates/gk_news2/css/template.css
```

In order to change this styling, unless there is a backend setting in your template's options, you will need a **css override**. Following this link: **[How do I override the CSS styles in my template?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/)**, you will find extended info on the proper way to create a **custom css** file for many well-know commercial Joomla templates (you are using a gavick template) - Johanpw's answer has covered this template provider as well.

But here is the bit of information you need:

> **Gavick Pro templates** ship with an empty overrides.css file in the /css/ subdirectory. But note that this file is not loaded by default,
>   you have to activate Override CSS in the Advanced Settings tab in the
>   template settings.

Gavick website provides more info here: **https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/custom-template-css**

After you have created your override css file, you need to write your css that will override the uppercase for h1.

So something like this should work:

```
h1 {
    text-transform: initial;
}
```

If you don't see a change, make sure you have cleared caches both browser's and Joomla's and that your css override files is loading.