# Change background image on t3 framework

Tags: development, templates, joomla-3.5, t3-framework

Hello i am using joomla template having t3 framework http://demo.themeparrot.com/runway/index.php/pages/about-us

you can see the black image banner at the backside of the title (About us).

i want to change it, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug or similar, you can see that the background image is implemented via CSS:

```
.tp-breadcrumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("/runway/templates/tp_runway/images/themeparrot/stars.png") repeat scroll 90% center;
}
```

You could replace the image file via FTP or similar or override the CSS as per [this answer to "How do I override the CSS styles in my template?"](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120).

Comment: I'm glad it helped @Amirali. The best way to show your appreciation on Stack Exchange websites is to upvote answers you find useful. This helps other users find the most useful answers in future.