# How to globally justify text in multiple existing articles on a joomla 3 site?

Tags: editor

I am trying to universally apply text justification to a number of existing articles. Is there some way to do this globally, or for all existing articles or do I have to go through the existing articles and manually set all of the text to justified?

Comment: Are you wanting to make it a default for the backend editor you are using?  If so, which are you using?  JCE, Tiny, etc?   Otherwise, the easiest thing would be to just add it to your template CSS for paragraphs and whatnot.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. I want the default to be justified and I want to update the existing articles to be the same. So, is this something I should do through CSS? Will that affect the editor's settings?

Comment: Then I would just add CSS to your template.  Preferably in a custom.css if it has it, if not at the bottom of the template.css or whatnot.  if you post a URL, I can tell you exact file and code and put into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please don't do this. Justified text on the web looks horrible, and there's no legitimate reason for wanting to do this globally.
2. If you really don't care about aesthetics, good typography or user experience then just add this to your template css:

   body { text-align: justify !important; }

Comment: Ideally, add custom CSS code to a custom.css file as per http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 or similar so changes are not overwritten by future template updates.