# What is the fastest way to integrate with Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.4, custom-component, integration

I promised to dev a small caritate project for the local government. It consists of a few pages, db tables, queries. I don't need tutorials about how a database works, what is MVC and other design patterns. I just like to integrate my small app with joomla, so it would have a menu point in a submenu and it would have nice URIs, send queries through an ORM and have a cronjob, etc...

I did some research, I need to use the menu manager to add a menu point and the extension manager to add a custom component. I made a basic hello world component based on a tutorial. I really don't have much time to complete the project, so I am looking for a tutorial or a documentation which is exactly about integration of existing apps. Is there something like that?

Thanks for the answers! I will probably never use PHP or Joomla again, so I don't care about the minus points, but please don't close the question, maybe somebody has an answer! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the fastest ways to add an application to Joomla (if you are not familiar with Joomla) is to install the free or paid version of [Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer/) or similar which allows you to embed code (e.g. PHP) directly into articles and custom HTML modules.

It's easy to find examples showing how use the Joomla API to read and write to the Joomla database.

Another thing you might need to learn is how best to add some custom styling and this can be found at [How do I override the CSS styles in my template?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/3877/120)

Comment: Isn't this sourcerer a security issue? Is it possible to use this only with superuser privileges?

Comment: You can change the plugin code to something less obvious but ultimately there is no easy way to restrict Sourcerer to administrators only. You can restrict who you give editing privileges to. A determined user could set their profile to editor = none and perhaps insert code anyway (although Text Filter settings can maybe minimise this risk).

Comment: I'll stick with custom components. There are many editors, and I think it is not wise to let them inject php. Thanks anyways!