# Proper Way to Migrate Custom Website to Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, custom-component

**Background:**

Thirteen months prior to this question, I voluntarily updated http://evangelismmission.com to its present state and design. Since that point, I have been maintaining it for Evangelism Mission.

Whenever I am emailed design changes or content changes, I make and test them on my machine, commit them with Git, FTP them onto the server, and check that everything took properly. In an endeavor to reduce the time and effort needed to update things, to make it easier for me to pass on the responsibilities to someone else, and to simplify website updates so that coding ability is no longer a prerequisite to updating the website, I would like to move this site to Joomla.

**Question:**

*What is the correct way to move websites with complicated elements to Joomla?*

In truth, these elements are not fancy, but they are too complicated to efficiently recreate in the article builder. Some need JavaScript -- all need CSS so that they look and behave properly.

Example:
[image]

Having researched and activated my brain, I believe I need to make a component(?) and insert it into the page where necessary... I theorize that the correct way to migrate a custom website to Joomla involves these steps:

1. Create template.
2. Create styles for template.
3. Make components...

Is this right? Am I missing something?

Comment: Read up on the difference between modules and components.    It looks like you could do most of that with modules, which are far simpler to build.

Comment: @RichardB: Thank you. I will take a look at modules.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly add CSS or JavaScript by creating a plugin or module but the quickest and easiest way to do this is probably using a third party extension such as the [EasyScript](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/easyscript) plugin or the [Flexi Custom Code](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code) module or similar. The advantage of using the module is that code can be assigned to specific pages.

There is often an option to add custom CSS in the template, depending on which template you are using. See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for details.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The Flexi Custom Code module looks like a very useful extension. +!