# Make 2 module positions the same height

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I'm struggling with something that should be really simple.

I have 2 modules side by side one displays a widgetkit slideshow the other a googlemap. I want them to display completely inline - i.e. the titles inline and then the top and bottom of the map to be inline with the top and bottom of the images in the slideshow. It doesn't seem to make a difference what height/width I use for the map it will not sit inline with the slideshow? Is there a simple way to specify the module height and to contain the content within those contraints?

The website can be found [here](http://dominionbodyrepairs.com/)

Would I be better off using a custom html module covering the full width here or is there a way to do it with css. It is the map that is causing a problem more than anything else.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Regards
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use some custom CSS (see https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for more details on creating a custom CSS file for your template) like this or similar:

```
@media (min-width:788px)
  .map-responsive iframe {
    height: 338px;
    margin-top: -12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neil, I tinkered a bit with it with the help of your code and this seems to have worked :)