# Disable submenu items on bottom of page in gantry 4?

Tags: module, submenu

I have really tried multiple settings, I cannot find the setting to disable the submenu item creation. 
How can I disable the submenu entries showing at the bottom of all pages? See here the issue: http://bit.ly/2QXfWBN

The submenus are either in

```
Position: content-bottom-a
Style: standard outline
```

or in

```
Position:
Style: submenu outline
```

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I cannot see any submenu items. If the problem persists please add some more detail to the original question.

Comment: @jamesgarrett the issue is still there (see at bottom in white background starting with bullets Kanzlei ...)

Comment: Have you have unpublished or deleted the menu module in content-bottom-a? If you have cache switched on (either global or a plugin), have you refreshed it since removing the module?

Comment: that is my issue. I could not find any module there. The only modules are main-menu on position-7 and a non-published also on position-7

Comment: You seem to be using a split menu that provides an option of putting the submenu items into a separate module position.  Is the submenu settings in mainmenu within the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gantry 4 templates, there are two places where you can assign a menu to a module position.

One is at Extensions -> Modules where you should be able to find a menu in the content-bottom-a module position.

The other is at Extensions -> Template -> Template Name -> Menu.

If neither of these places reveals how the menu is being displayed, then a short term or long term solution might be to hide the module via a custom CSS like this or similar:

```
#rt-content-bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120 for details on how to create a Custom CSS file.

Comment: Neil, the second option did the trick! big thx!
I have been there but somehow I have overseen the split configuration for the submenu. Hope I can soon switch to newer Gantry5...
Since I could not disable the submenu i had to use the CSS-disable (sigh...)