# Is there any one to use the mod_menu as we please? *Modifying the backend*

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, css, jhtml

so I've been asked to make a special menu for a website.I'm using the default module that is mod_menu.  The issue is I want to modify the HTML Structure to that module.

But I heard modify the default module isn't good practice.

Is there any way to customize it without affecting the actual module.
I am struggling a lot on the css side because of that issue. If I could just change directly that would save me a lot of time.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the HTML structure, create a template override. This can be done through Template Manager or by manually copying files through FTP. The documentation already covers this very well:

- [How to override the output from the Joomla!
  core](https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core)
- [Understanding Output Overrides - Module Layout
  Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides)
- [How to use the Template Manager - Creating
  Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides)

Answer (score 0):

Most templates give the option to add a custom css file that allows the user to override the styles of everything in the front-end. Search the documentation of your template to see how to add one and then add all your custom styles for your menu in that file.

Check this Q/A as well, as it's relative on how to add/override the css of a Joomla site: [How do I override the CSS styles in my template?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template)

As a side note, the mod_menu has no css file in it - so I am not sure what you are struggling with.

Comment: Well the HTML structure is hardcoded in the module. If I want for example add and new html TAG in the menu I need to play in the mod_menu function.