# How can I make changes to JoomlArt's "Ja Mero" template's style sheet?

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, css, joomlart

I'm not quite sure how Joomla's file structure works.  I am using the [Ja Mero template](https://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/ja-mero) from JoomlArt, but haven't used it much.  It looks like the [T3 Framework](http://www.t3-framework.org/).

The generated filepath appears to be:  `t3-assets/css/css-d8be1-56919.css`

I can't find this style sheet to make changes.  Can someone help me to find it?

Comment: While you wait for support, please continue to research and attempt to self-solve.  If you manage to resolve this yourself, you are welcome to post an answer to your own question.  Please also take the [tour] to better acquaint yourself with this community and earn your first badge.  Do you have a login for JoomlArt? Did you have a look through: https://www.joomlart.com/forums/t/ja-mero ?

Comment: There's probably an answer to this question at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120