# Joomla with Helix3 Framework, remove whitespaces above and below smartslider

Tags: css

I am designing a new site in joomla using helix3 framework. In the "about us"section i use smartslider 3 and what i need is not to have any white spaces, above and bellow... if possible. Is there a way to do this !!!???

Thank you all in advance.

https://willow.edk.gr/index.php/about-en
enter image description here[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: The site URL you have provided is not working. What you want to do can commonly be done with CSS.

Comment: This should be helpful as well: [How to override the CSS Styles of my Template](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3877/how-do-i-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to modify the css.

By setting `#sp-main-body { display: none; }` the empty node is no longer rendered.

To specify a specific page, you can isolate the page by its `itemid` in the `<body>` tag.

To only modify the css on your home page, you can first target its unique body tag class then specify the deeper element to assign the new styling:

```
body.itemid-101 #sp-main-body {
    display: none;
}
```

See the element in your browser tools:

[image]

To implement this styling change, add/modify the custom.css file in the template's css folder.

A Google search will deliver lots of results that will confirm this guidance.

- [Add custom css to Helix3 and SP PageBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32949348/2943403)
- [I Am Having Issues Creating Custom Css Styles In Helix3](https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/i-am-having-issues-creating-custom-css-styles-in-helix3)
- [Custom CSS In Helix 3](https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/custom-css-in-helix-3?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=51bc6d7dc91836bc5ba530633c9f6ad9ac54c360-1595414045-0-AbRmZZ-7SEBFMvCPdrYL2XSVX5MI5m2LItDKKfPuuQvAFtlBO4ytEhGhL3gqOPsZCV6oMhsb5wf1QtjaqUoAZBHRrJtdH2XPMYITDN-QSFG2wq4ZqVmEvgl5Z4SzU69X1_3JDVmZ6seZ7YbJ1Q44HSsPQXtCalGHphPNxv7OTilOeFWLuFSkx-SFaqhA56fkrAAQjYVuBr0uhNotcVTPHG7p4zmpdH6Y8nkamAzxCfKZQTSyHTAa_bjB3Mn1IoJvX5Uq3MO807KBxhj6s_IZKIVEGO7o0DRmVDbf7PJTEPhhZeTjcVEgTYzTCq4AXjyAnA)
- [How do Create Custom CSS Style in Helix Joomla Templates](https://pcmshaper.com/post/how-do-override-the-css-styles-in-my-template/64)
- ...and many, many, many more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...
Where do i make this change... for the css. ?

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Hello again, I added the custom code but the result is not the one expected.
All details are lost ... from all menuitems such as, AboutUs / Destination  etc. 
I see a white page.

Comment: How about specifying only the front page... `#sp-smart-slider-frontpage #sp-main-body {...}`?

Comment: Νο ... No change at all... its like before the custom code edit.
The problem is not in the frontpage... its in the Aboutus / Destinations etc sections.

Comment: Okay, now I have it: `body.itemid-101 #sp-main-body { display: none; }`

Comment: It works for the FrontPage.. .but not for the other sections.
I have it enabled so that you can check it.
Thank again and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not willing to spend a few hours combing through every page and manually tweaking each layout, then checking if it looks good in all viewport dimensions.  So my parting advice is... use the brower's developer tools, click through a given page's dom elements and remove padding and margin (or possibly use negative values) until the whitespace is removed.  When you have a collection of styling changes, follow the advice in my answer to isolate the given page and the specific dom elements and save to custom.css.

Comment: Thank you for all your help... but i am not so accustomed with css coding to fidle arround eith it myself.
If anyone else has an idea about this.. please feel free. 
Thank again.

Comment: I find toying with css to be tedious and often disappointing as so many declarations need to be written to enjoy satisfactory responsiveness.  If this template doesn't serve you, there are many other templates for Joomla.

Comment: I've made some changes on my own that fixed the top margin. 
What i did was in the layout of Helix 3 i added 2 more rows one for every menuitem where each module will appear and now its OK. 
Is there a way to reduce the white space at the bottom ???